# Disabling Login Shake Effect

Tags: macos, high-sierra

Is there any way to disable the login "shake" effect when an incorrect password is entered? All the results I found while googling were about an unrelated issue (how to disable the "shake mouse pointer to locate" accessibility feature). I'm running macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

Comment: The same reason that disabling the "dock bounce" feature is an option -- because it's visually disruptive. Most things on the system shouldn't be moving of their own accord, imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shake animation is the visual indicator for letting the user know that the password was incorrectly entered. Therefore, if it could be disabled, there would be no way for the user to know that they entered the wrong password.

There is no way (either via System Preference or a hack) to disable the animation.

Comment: This is frustrating. After the prompt "shakes its head" at me, I get no remaining indication of the prompt status. Also, it makes me feel as if I'm being mocked. I want technology this is functional, not "cute"